# Symfony logout handler

Tags: symfony

I am just trying already couple of hours to figure out how to get flash message working after logout action.

**security.yml**

```
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /check
            login_path: /login
            failure_handler: authentication_handler
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            success_handler: authentication_handler
```

**config.yml**

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Project\LoginBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
```

**AuthenticationHandler.php**

```
class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {       
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');       
        $request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());

        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) 
    {
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        $request->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Wylogowano');


        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }
}
```

view hello after login

```
{% extends "ProjectCMSBundle:Secured:layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title "Hello " ~ name %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>

    <a href="{{ path('_project_secured_hello_admin', { 'name': name }) }}">Hello resource secured for <strong>admin</strong> only.</a>
{% endblock %}

{% set code = code(_self) %}
```

view login form

```
{% extends 'ProjectCMSBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Title
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


    <form action="{{ path("_project_security_check") }}" method="post" id="login">
        <div class="data">
          <div class="username">
              <label for="username">&nbsp;</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
          </div>

          <div class="password">
              <label for="password">&nbsp;</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
          </div>
        </div>
    {% if error %}
        <div class="error">{{ error.message|trans({},'messages') }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% set code = code(_self) %}
```

layout main template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/project/css/demo.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="symfony-wrapper">

        {% if app.session.flash('error') %}
            <div class="flash-message">
                {{ app.session.flash('error')|trans }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if app.session.flash('success') %}
            <div class="flash-message">
                {{ app.session.flash('success')}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if app.user %}
          {% block content_header %}
            <ul id="menu">
                {% block content_header_more %}
                {% endblock %}
            </ul>

            <div style="clear: both"></div>
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="symfony-content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        {#{% if code is defined %}
            <h2>Code behind this page</h2>
            <div class="symfony-content">{{ code|raw }}</div>
        {% endif %}#}
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is that it seems that flash message is getting dropped during redirect.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 20):

Session is destroyed on logout. But you can change this behavior by adding `invalidate_session: false` in your `security.yml` file.

```
logout:
    path:   /logout
    success_handler: authentication_handler
    invalidate_session: false
```

Check the [reference documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) to have more information.

If you still want to invalidate session, you can set a flag in your Request directly and use it with a Kernel listener.

Comment: in case of using **invalidate_session** Flash appears but RedirectResponse did not happened.

Comment: I would suggest considering the symfony 2.1 version - it has revamped flash messages as well as other compatibility breaks for the better.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from @Olivier Dolbeau but it no longer applies, now the recommended approach is to use a [logout subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#customizing-logout) or [logout listener](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-logout-customization):

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LogoutEvent;

class LogoutSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [LogoutEvent::class => 'onLogout'];
    }

    public function onLogout(LogoutEvent $event): void
    {
        // $url = '...';
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url)); // redirect to custom URL
    }
}
```