# Symfony 2 - Setting a Flash Message outside of Controller

Tags: symfony

I have a logout Listener where I'd like to set a flash message showing a logout confirmation message.

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Security\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
  private $security;  

  public function __construct(SecurityContext $security)
  {
    $this->security = $security;
  }

  public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
  {
    $request->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'You have been successfully been logged out.');

    $response = new RedirectResponse('login');
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Here is my services.yml (as it pertains to this):

```
logout_listener:
   class:  ACME\MyBundle\Security\Listeners\LogoutListener
   arguments: [@security.context]
```

This is generating an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFlashBag() on a non-object
```

How do I set a flashBag message in this context?

Also, how do get access to the router so I can generate the url (via $this->router->generate('login')) instead of passing in a hard-coded url?

**Resolution Note**

To get the flash to work, you must tell your security.yml config not invalidate the session on logout; otherwise, the session will be destroyed and your flash will never appear.

```
logout:
    path: /logout
        success_handler: logout_listener
        invalidate_session: false
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should inject the services for session and router into the LogoutListener and use them to perform these tasks. This is the way to do it in yml:

```
logout_listener: 
class: ACME\MyBundle\Security\Listeners\LogoutListener 
arguments: [@security.context, @router, @session]
```

Then in your class you write:

```
class LogoutListener implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $security;
    private $router;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security, Router $router, Session $session)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }
    [...]
```

When you want to use the session now you can just say:

```
$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'You have been successfully been logged out.');
```

And in the same way you can use the router service to generate routes.

Comment: I added my services.yml. How do I add inject the services? I presume I need to use arguments, but I'm unsure of the syntax to inject these.

Comment: This shows you a basic example about injecting services, read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: My session is apparently getting destroyed so the flash is getting wiped. I thought the actual logging out was already done before onLogoutSuccess() gets called?

Comment: My guess is that onLogoutSuccess is called after the logout, yes. But this is out of the scope of this question, that was about how to use session and router inside your class.

Comment: Looks like I have to set a flag to not invalidate the session onLogout. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043672/symfony-logout-handler

Answer (score 3):

The answers are very old on this post. 10 years later (2022), Symfony allows to deal with flashes very easily outside of a controller using the `FlashBagInterface`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $flash;

    public function __construct(FlashBagInterface $flash)
    {
        $this->flash = $flash;
    }

    public function myRandomMethod(): string
    {
        // ...
        $this->flash->add('success', 'This is a success!');
    }
}
```

Comment: This way is deprecated in symfony 6. Go through session is the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Session object (as well as any other service) trough the service container:

```
$session = $ServiceContainer->get('session');
$session->setFlash('notice', 'Message');
```

The way you can access to the service container in different ways:

- From a controller or any container aware class: just use $this->get('session');
- From a service:  you have to inject the service container object as Aldo Said

Comment: This approach works but it is not the correct way to do dependency injection. You should avoid injecting the container everywhere, that's using the container to implement a service locator pattern, that has two major drawbacks: all your classes (i.e. your model) will depend on the service rather than on other pertinent parts of the system (making it impossible to reuse them outside symfony) and all the dependencies will be solved at runtime rather than at "compile-time", i.e. when symfony dumps the container before bootstrapping. Inject only the services you need, that's the best practice!