# Symfony SecurityBundle: how to stay on the same page after logout?

Tags: symfony, logout, symfony-security

The logout process is handled by `logout` section in `security.yml`

```
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
```

where `target` option defines where the user shoud be redirected to after logout.

**The question is:** Is possible to customize this behaviour (like in `form_login` section where setting `use_referer: true` allowes to be redirected to the referer page) ?

**What I need:** I need to stay on the same page where "logout" has been clicked since, of course, it does not require to be authenticated with a role.

I didn't find any solution without re-implementing whole logout process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to configure custom logout handler. In that handler you can override the default Symfony behaviour.

```
secured_area: 
        #.....
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            success_handler: some.service.id
        #......
```

This answer can give you a good idea on how to implement it [Symfony logout handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043672/symfony-logout-handler)